# Nagios exclude a service for a single host

Tags: monitoring, nagios

### How i can exclude a inherited service for a singe host, without editing my service file?

---

i have in my **conf.d** directory many files, one for each host, hostgroup, template and service.

**hg_linux-server.cfg**

```
define hostgroup{
    hostgroup_name hg_linux-server
    alias Linux-Server
}
```

**check_swap.cfg**

```
define service{
    service_description check_swap
    check_command check_nrpe!check_swap
    hostgroup_name hg_linux-server
    [...] #more options...
}
```

**t_linux-server.cfg**

```
define host{
    name t_linux-server
    hostgroups hg_linux-server
    register 0
    [...] #more options...
}
```

**examplehost.domain.local.cfg**

```
define host{
    use t_linux-server
    host_name examplehost
    alias examplehost.domain.local
    address 192.168.0.2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't... without editing the service definition.

The way to exclude `examplehost` from your service is:

```
define service{
  service_description check_swap
  check_command check_nrpe!check_swap
  hostgroup_name hg_linux-server
  host_name !examplehost
  [...] #more options...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

create a new hostgroup:

```
define hostgroup{
     hostgroup_name hg_no-check-swap
     alias exclude check_swap
     register 0
}
```

add the member to the host

```
define host{
    use t_linux-server
    host_name examplehost
    alias examplehost.domain.local
    address 192.168.0.2
    hostgroups hg_no-check-swap
}
```

and exclude the hostgroup

```
define service{
    service_description check_swap
    check_command check_nrpe!check_swap
    hostgroup_name hg_linux-server,!hg_no-check-swap
    [...] #more options...
}
```

now i can delete the examplehost.domain.local.cfg file, without errors.
**Nagios Core 4.3.4**